# Audio capture IOS after vibrate

Tags: ios, xcode, audio, avaudiorecorder, vibration

I am working on an app that require recording audio from user after pressing a button. When btn is pressed, the phone must vibrate and then start audio record. Its working just fine but my issue is that audio record is also capturing the buzz sound from the vibrate.
Is their a way to decrease the duration of vibrate?
Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would approach this problem.

- You cannot increase or decrease the duration of vibrate feature. Apple doesn't allow us developers to do that.
- Use a NSTimer
- Call your recording function about 1 or 0.5 seconds after vibrate action

  [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
      target:self
      selector:@selector(recordSomething)
      userInfo:nil
      repeats:NO];